# Generic method inheritance: VS and Xamarin Studio yield different results; which is right?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, mono, overriding

In an inheritance hierarchy, I have the following generic method implemented:

```
public class Base
{
    public virtual T Foo<T>()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base");
        return default(T);
    }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public override T Foo<T>()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Derived");
        return default(T);
    }
}

public class DerivedDerived : Derived
{
    public override T Foo<T>()
    {
        base.Foo<string>();
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

The crucial part here is that in the method implementation in `DerivedDerived` I am invoking the method of the *base* class with a specific type (`string`).

When I compile this in Visual Studio (2012) or LinqPad and execute the following statement:

```
var x = new DerivedDerived().Foo<string>();
```

the output is what I intuitively expect:

```
Derived
```

However, if I compile and run the same code in Xamarin Studio 4.0 (Windows or Mac, on Windows it does not seem to matter if I compile and run with .NET or Mono C#), the output is:

```
Base
```

**What would be the correct result here?**

Paragraph 7.6.8 of the *C# Language Specification 5.0* contains the following statement:

> When a base-access references a virtual function member (a method,
>   property, or indexer), the determination of which function member to
>   invoke at run-time (§7.5.4) is changed. The function member that is
>   invoked is determined by finding the most derived implementation
>   (§10.6.3) of the function member with respect to B (instead of with
>   respect to the run-time type of this, as would be usual in a non-base
>   access). Thus, within an override of a virtual function member, a
>   base-access can be used to invoke the inherited implementation of the
>   function member. If the function member referenced by a base-access is
>   abstract, a binding-time error occurs.

At first glance I would say that the most derived implementation, i.e. `Derived.Foo`, would  be called from `DerivedDerived.Foo`, unless I somehow short-circuit the inheritance hierarchy by applying a specific type in the generic method invocation?

Comment: May be due to Mono limitations: http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/limitations

Comment: @friism Many thanks for the link, but I do not think this is the issue. The compiled code was contained in a .NET/Mono runtime console application project, Monotouch was not involved in this case.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the type parameter shouldn't be involved at all in resolving the method. Looks like a bug in Mono...

Comment: related: [all your base are not belong to you](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/12/13/all-your-base-do-not-belong-to-you.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct result is the following, which is clear from the way the specification is written.

```
Derived
```

Edit: The specification says:

> The function member that is invoked is determined by finding the most derived implementation (§10.6.3) of the function member with respect to B (instead of with respect to the run-time type of this, as would be usual in a non-base access).

The base class of `DerivedDerived` is `Derived`. The most derived implementation of `Foo<T>` with respect to `Derived` is `Derived.Foo<T>`. That is the method which is called, not `Base.Foo<T>`.

Comment: So why does Xamarin Studio/Mono call `Base.Foo<string>()` instead of `Derived.Foo<string>()`? Is it unequivocally a bug in Mono?

Comment: I have reported the issue as a [bug in Mono](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=15523). If the Xamarin team confirms that this is indeed a bug on the Mono side, I will accept this answer.

Comment: [The Mono fix!](https://github.com/mono/mono/commit/fcad876ef1cf57a0b8b066a2b5080885e32e8fa2)